# How do I make the lines having classes fm and then sm appear one after the other using jQuery inside the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make a chatbox kind of interface while learning jQuery and I wanted to know how to make the lines having classes `fm` and `sm` appear one after the other. The second line just goes out of the box.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>WSDC STUDENT PORTAL</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row head">


      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><span class="name">Prashanth Sateesh</span></div>
      <div class="col-md-7"></div>





    </div>

    <br><br><br>

    <div class="row bot">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="chatbox"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>




    </div>
    <div class="fm message"><strong> Hi.I am Prashanth and I'm studying Electronics Engineering at NIT,Warangal in India.</strong>

    </div>
    <div class="sm message"><strong>Welcome to my website</strong>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".chatbox").html($(".fm").hide().fadeIn(1500))
        var prev = $(".chatbox").html();
        $(".chatbox").html(prev + "<br>" + ($(".sm").hide().fadeIn(1500)))




      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}

.head {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF0F5;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.bot {
  height: 400px;
}

.chatbox {
  background-color: #00FA9A;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.message {
  background-color: #87CEFA;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your messages class is displaying as inline-block. If you want items to appear on a new line, you have to display the messages as 'block' or insert a line break manually.

```css
.message {
  background-color: #87CEFA;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fm message">
  <strong> Hi.I am Prashanth and I'm studying Electronics Engineering at NIT,Warangal in India.</strong>
</div>
<div class="sm message">
  <strong>Welcome to my website</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems a little over engineered. You could try this.

```
$(".fm").fadeIn(1500).delay(300).fadeOut(1500).promise().done(function () {
    $(".sm").fadeIn(1500);
});
```

The second fadeIn waits until the first has finished animating with the .promise. I've also adding in a delay on the fadeIn fadeOut of the first message so there is time to read it.

Comment: Forgot to mention you would need to set the messages to display:none in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? You can use the only CSS.
fm appears and then sm appears.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
}

.head {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF0F5;
  padding-top: 0.6%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.bot {
  height: 400px;
}

.chatbox {
  background-color: #00FA9A;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.message {
  background-color: #87CEFA;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.fm, .sm {opacity:0}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0%   { display:block;opacity:0 }
  100% { display:block;opacity: 1; }
}


@-moz-keyframes fadein {
   0%   { display:block;opacity:0 }
  100% { display:block;opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    0%   { display:block;opacity:0 }
  100% { display:block;opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadein {
   0%   { display:block;opacity:0 }
  100% { display:block;opacity: 1; }
}

.fm{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:  fadein 2s forwards forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:    fadein 2s forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:       fadein 2s forwards; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

.sm{
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s 1s forwards; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:  fadein 2s 1s  forwards; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:    fadein 2s 1s  forwards; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:       fadein 2s 1s  forwards; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    
    <div class="fm message"><strong> Hi.I am Prashanth and I'm studying Electronics Engineering at NIT,Warangal in India.</strong></div>
    <div class="sm message"><strong>Welcome to my website</strong></div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```